# My intersection() method returns an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried to make a piece of code that shows me only the common values of user input as compared to a set list. I continue to get the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Here's what I've done:

```
    main_List = ["name", "job", "backstory", "all"]
    provided_List = []

 def main()
    resp = input("Do you need a name, job, backstory, or all?")
    provided_List.append(resp.split())
    update_Set = provided_List.intersection(main_List)
    print(update_Set)

 main()
```

Essentially, I'm trying to ignore everything but key words the user inputs. As far as I can tell I am doing everything exactly like the examples but it still isn't coming out the way I want. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use `set` methods on `list` objects. You need to cast both `main_list` and `provided_list` as `set` objects:

```py
main_options = {"name", "job", "backstory", "all"}
prompt = "Select any of name, job, backstory, or all: "
resp = main_options & set(input(prompt).split())
```

Usage:

```py
Select any of name, job, backstory, or all: name
# resp: {'name'}

Select any of name, job, backstory, or all:
# resp: set()

Select any of name, job, backstory, or all: name backstory job
# resp: {'backstory', 'job', 'name'}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks for the clarification. I was trying to convert the lists into sets but I'm not sure if that is possible or I was just doing it wrong.

Comment: Glad I could help. You certainly could cast to `set`, but you might as well just construct `set` objects from the get-go and cast to `list` if/when you need to do so.